# Почему элементы массива меняются при каждом вызове функции? И как сделать правильно?

Tags: c++

```
int *read_array(int N) // Функция вводящая элементы и размерность динамического массива (от 1 до N)
{
    int *read_array = new int[N];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        read_array[i] = rand() %20-10; // Генерация чисел от -10 до 10
    }
 
    return read_array;
}
 
void print_array(int read_array[],int N)// Вывод элементов динамического массива в прямом порядке
{
    cout << "\nВывод массива в прямом порядке из " << N << " элементов" << endl;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        cout << read_array[i] << endl;
    }
 
}
 
void print_array_rev(int read_array[], int N)// Вывод элементов динамического массива в прямом порядке
{
    cout << "\nВывод массива в обратном порядке из " << N << " элементов" << endl;
 
    for (int i = (N-1); i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << read_array[i] << endl;
    }
 
 
}
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int N = 0; //количество элементов массива, количество элементов в массиве 

    cout << "Введите размерность и количество элементов массива" << endl;

    cin >> N;

    cout << "Введенное число = " << N << endl;

    read_array(N); // Функция вводящая элементы и размерность динамического массива

    print_array(read_array(N), N); // Вывод элементов динамического массива в прямом порядке

    print_array_rev(read_array(N), N); // Вывод элементов динамического массива в обратном порядке
```

Comment: А где вы вообще работаете с массивом? У вас в main вводится только одно число, и все...

Comment: Называть функции и параметры функций одинаковыми именами - это сильно!

Comment: Поправил main, не заметил что не зацепил. Названия переменных из условия самой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `main` Ваша `read_array` возвращает массив в пустоту. Нужно сохранить возвращаемый ею указатель, который потом передавать другим функциям:

```
int* arr = read_array(N);

print_array(arr, N);

print_array_rev(arr, N);
```

Вы же каждый раз создавали новый массив вызывая функцию `read_array`. Это, кстати, приводит к утечке памяти. Не забывайте освобождать её с помощью `delete[]`.